# Ruby installation not showing up after installing and uninstalling from source

Tags: ruby

I installed Ruby 1.9.2 from source and was using it for a while but now I wanted to start using RVM, so I uninstalled my source Ruby 1.9.2 installation and installed ruby using `sudo apt-get install ruby`. However, now when I run `ruby --version` I get:

```
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

When I call `which ruby` I get nothing.  My `/etc/environment` (which I've sourced) contains:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin"
```

When I run `sudo apt-get install ruby` it says that it's already installed. When I `ls /usr/bin`, `ruby` appears but it's in red (not sure what that means). If I `cd /usr/bin/ruby` or `less /usr/bin/ruby` it gives me a "No such file or directory"

When I run `dpkg -L ruby` it gives me:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/ruby
/usr/share/doc/ruby/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/index.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ch-ruby.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ch-module_packages.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ch-programs.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ap-build_dependencies.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ap-ruby1.8_bundled_modules.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.html/ap-transition_1.6_to_1.8.html
/usr/share/doc/ruby/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/ruby/copyright
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/ruby/ruby-policy.sgml.gz
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/testrb
/usr/bin/erb
/usr/bin/ruby
/usr/share/man/man1/testrb.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/erb.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
```

...so it's definitely installing to `/usr/bin/ruby`

It seems like Ruby is installed, but bash can't find it because something is wrong with `/usr/bin/ruby`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `/usr/bin/ruby` is a symbolic link, whose target has been deleted.

If you type the command `ls -l /usr/bin/ruby`, that will display info about the file in long format. If it is a symbolic link, then the target of the link will be shown. This what what that command shows for me (I'm on OS X):

> [10:14 PM]bin $ls -l ruby lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Jul 28  2010
>   ruby ->
>   ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby

Assuming it is a symbolic link, go to the target of the link and see if that file exists. I'm guessing that it doesn't, and the ruby installation script only checks for the existence of /usr/bin/ruby to determine if ruby is installed or not. If you delete `/usr/bin/ruby` this will hopefully fix the issue.

Comment: I tried this already. However I had forgotten about `ls -l`. That gives me back: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 2011-07-17 22:22 /usr/bin/ruby -> ruby1.8`. There is no `/usr/bin/ruby1.8` even though `dpkg -L ruby1.8` lists that as an installation location. I'm not sure what that means...

Comment: It sounds like ruby is half installed, or maybe when you uninstalled your ruby build from source, you didn't get everything. I'm not sure at this point, this is the limit of my Unix knowledge I'm afraid. :(